# While-true loop lopping sometimes

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, while-loop

Why this loop executes for the first time, and then *waits* until condition in `if` clause is true?

```
Random rand = new Random();
int i = 0;
while (true) {
    currencyList.put(Currency.EUR, BigDecimal.valueOf(7*rand.nextDouble()+1.2));
    currencyList.put(Currency.HRK, BigDecimal.valueOf(7*rand.nextDouble()+1.2));
    currencyList.put(Currency.NOK, BigDecimal.valueOf(7*rand.nextDouble()+1.2));
    currencyList.put(Currency.USD, BigDecimal.valueOf(7*rand.nextDouble()+1.2));
    System.out.println(currencyList);
    Socket sock = null;
    if ( (sock = serversocket.accept()) != null) {
        System.out.println("Client " + (++i) + "connected...");
        new ServerThreadB(sock,username).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `serversocket.accept()` **blocks**.

Comment: Didn't know that. I recently started to work with Threads and Sockets. Thank you. I guess I should make new Thread that calculates currencyList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation, it says "The method blocks until a connection is made.": https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()

Answer (score 1):

ServerSocket stops the program from progressing until a connection is made.

To limit the time it stops the program you can use the setSoTimeout(long milli) method  with milliseconds to determine the time taken till the socket gives up.